# How to skip / mock a test when no block is provided in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actiondispatch

I was having trouble figuring out how to stub out tests in Rails in the manner that Rspec does, without the rest of the Rspec baggage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure where this belongs, I put it in a file called:

`config/initializers/integration_test_overrides.rb`

But there might be a better place for it.

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def self.test(test_string)
    if block_given?
      super
    else
      super(test_string) do
        skip
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now when you call a test without the block:

`test "endpoint accepts xml input"`

The test will automatically skip it.